# Why my Toast not showing up ,android programming

Tags: android, android-studio, toast

I wrote code where when clicking specific radio button shows up toast of certain message ,but when i clicked why no toast pops up ?
why toast is not showing up?
I wrote code where when clicking specific radio button shows up toast of certain message ,but when i clicked why no toast pops up ?
why toast is not showing up?

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RadioGroup radioGroup;
int id;
String text = "radio button 1!";
String text2="radioi button 2";
String text3="radio button 3";

int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
    id = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
}
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {


    switch(id) {
        case R.id.radioButton:
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, text, duration);
            toast.show();

            break;
        case R.id.radioButton2:
            Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(this, text2, duration);
            toast2.show();

            break;
        case R.id.radioButton3:
            Toast toast3 = Toast.makeText(this, text3, duration);
            toast3.show();
            default:


    }
}
}
```

This is the xml layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.ai_agamcompaq.radio.MainActivity">
<RadioGroup
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/radio_group">
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New RadioButton"
    android:id="@+id/radioButton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
    android:layout_marginTop="115dp" />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New RadioButton"
    android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/radioButton"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp" />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New RadioButton"
    android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/radioButton2"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp" />


</RadioGroup>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please update your XML too

Comment: have you tried to check that whether your `onRadioButtonClicked` is called or not?

Comment: There are already 3 correct answers here, accept 1 and upvote others. But bofore that, try them. Murat, Samus and I have already given the correct answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## EDIT: Full working code

### [image]

`MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    // Declare the messages to show
    private String text1 = "radio button 1";
    private String text2 = "radio button 2";
    private String text3 = "radio button 3";

    private int mToastDuarion = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id. radio_group);
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int id) {

        switch(id) {
            case R.id.radioButton:
                Toast.makeText(this, text1, mToastDuarion).show();
                break;

            case R.id.radioButton2:
                Toast.makeText(this, text2, mToastDuarion).show();
                break;

            case R.id.radioButton3:
                Toast.makeText(this, text3, mToastDuarion).show();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

`layout_main.xml` (it's your same XML without `onClick` defined):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radio_group"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New RadioButton"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="115dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New RadioButton"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/radioButton"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New RadioButton"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_marginTop="52dp" />
        
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i know this way by implenting it works with Toggle button too. but what if i use my own method by using onclick in xml

Comment: I don't think `OnClick` is a good choice here. They are not `Button`s. This is what `onCheckedChanged` was created for.

Comment: I have to agree. onCheckChanged parameters are telling of the functions purpose. An onClick listener simply gets the View that was clicked as an argument, where onCheckChanged gets the specific id, which is exactly what is needed to process the event.

Comment: @SamusArin There is of course a reason for `OnCheckedChanged` to exist, thanks, however, you are wrong regarding the `id`s. You can get the `id` of the clicked `View` with method `View.getId()`.

Comment: Exactly my point, onCheckedChanged is giving you exactly what you need, there is no need derive this information... I may not have gotten my point across well, it's just a subtle concept no biggie... FWIW, there are other, less conflict-inducing, ways to tell someone that (you think) they are wrong. Crafting words is a delicate and subtle art that will undoubtedly server you well here. I'm chill and in general dgaf, but i could definitely see how someone could interpret your "your wrong" comment snoody and get their panties all up in a bunch :)

Comment: i tried your code mr jonzarate , but showing error in  "radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);" and why would u implement CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener instead of RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener

Comment: @indian0girl Check the `Activity` definition on top. Did you add: `implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener` and import the needed classes?

Comment: first i used ur implentation which CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener and even implemented override the needed class. but in the line "radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this)" it show error saying setoncheckedchangelistener in radio group cannot be applied , than i tried another implementation called "RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener" it doesnt give error run perfectly but toast doesnt shows up again

Comment: @indian0girl It is working for me. Let me upload the whole code. Also, don't forget to **REMOVE** `android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"` from the `RadioButton`s in the XML .

Comment: @indian0girl I edited my post with a picture as a proof. Try it and report back please.

Comment: ya i even copy pasted your whole code still doesnt work. there is no error but Toast still dont show when i click. is there problem with my emulator or studio

Comment: @indian0girl Well, we can't help you with that. I showed you the code, if you can't make it work, maybe you should read some books on how to use Android Studio. I can only suggest you re-create a new project and paste the code there.

Comment: i am using genymotion

Comment: may be i have anything more to import?, i already imported this import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

Answer (score 2):

Your `switch` statement is incorrect. You will never see a checked box, because you to have ask for the one who got checked.

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {

switch(view.getId()) {
    case R.id.radioButton:
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, text, duration);
        toast.show();
        break;
    case R.id.radioButton2:
        Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(this, text2, duration);
        toast2.show();
        break;
    case R.id.radioButton3:
        Toast toast3 = Toast.makeText(this, text3, duration);
        toast3.show();
        default:
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write one line code...

Toast.makeText(context, "Your text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: You can also change time as Toast.LENGTH.LONG

Comment: How does it make a difference

Comment: context ?? i wrote "context" didnt  work, u mean what should i replace with context word

Comment: no i meant writing a one line code, like you started your answer saying write a one line code.

Comment: You can use context of your activity. ..context=MainActivity.this;

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {

    //please update the ID
    id = view.getId();

    switch(id) {
        case R.id.radioButton:
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, text, duration);
            toast.show();

            break;
        case R.id.radioButton2:
            Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(this, text2, duration);
            toast2.show();

            break;
        case R.id.radioButton3:
            Toast toast3 = Toast.makeText(this, text3, duration);
            toast3.show();
       default:
    }
}
```

> You were not updating the ID, so switch statement was always going to default.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to JonZarate's answer, you could also try this:

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int id) {

    string text = ((TextView)group.findViewById(id)).getText();
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, text, duration);
    toast.show();
}
```